# Trying to add all log in information when user is logged in on the system

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
def main():

    username = input('Enter your user name: ')
    pw = input('Enter your password: ')
    if username and pw:
        print(f'Your now log in {username}')
        f = open ("user_information.txt", "w+")
        f.write(f'User Name {username} is log in now!')

main()
```

My code is running but my problem is every time I enter new user information it won't save in notepad where data information is save

Comment: 0.) use with context when operating on files, 1.) no f.close(), 2.) w+ will recreate the file all the time, use `"a"` instead. 3. You never test if the pw is valid, just that it and the name are not `''`, ... - Please go over some python tutorials for beginners and read the respective parts of the documentation about file access - f.e. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: The file `write()` method doesn't automatically added a newline to the data (unlike the `print()` function), so you need to add a `'\n'` to it yourself. Also, output sent to a file is often buffered, so after the `f.write()` line add a `f.close()` to force the data to actually be written to the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestions and information sir @PatrickArtner

Comment: and also sir @martineau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For writing into a file you should use the `with` statement, it handles the opening and closing automatically (the closing part is missing in your code). Probably it's not saving because you're note closing the file, try something like this:

```py
def main():

    username = input('Enter your user name: ')
    pw = input('Enter your password: ')
    if username and pw:
        print(f'Your now log in {username}')
        with open("user_information.txt", "wa") as f:
            f.write(f'User Name {username} is log in now!')

main()
```